# Infinite Reboot Loop

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, boot-loop, htc-evo

I have a HTC EVO 4G (aka Supersonic) running Android 2.3.5 (aka Gingerbread) and last night I turned it off because it was running low on power. I connected it to the charger before going to bed and called it a night, my normal process (except for shutting it down).

This morning I turn it on and it starts up with the device screen (HTC EVO<sup>TM</sup> 4G) and then a few seconds later it shows the Sprint 4G animation, and usually after that it loads the OS and you slide down continue but now it just reboots again and again in an infinite loop. I can only stop it by pulling the battery.

Anyone experience this? Know what's causing it? Have a solution to it? I need the phone and its critical that I resolve this as soon as possible. Thanks everyone.

<sub>**Update - 12/18/13**</sub>

I went ahead and cleared the cache and the dalvik cache and still couldn't get it to boot into the OS, it would load the slide screen and then freeze up for a second and go back into the loop. From then on, it wouldn't even get to that screen, just would reboot after the startup animation.

I was not even running a custom ROM, just the stock ROM rooted but went ahead and flashed a stock ROM back on it and got it up and running but still bugs me that I had to lose all my customization and start over without knowing what the heck went wrong.

Anyone have any ideas?